# Cleaning up Spark history logs

Tags: apache-spark

We have long running EMR cluster where we submit Spark jobs. I see that over time the HDFS fills up with the Spark application logs which sometimes renders a host unhealthy as viewed by EMR/Yarn (?).

Running `hadoop fs -R -h /` shows [1] which clearly shows no application logs have ever been deleted.

We have set the `spark.history.fs.cleaner.enabled` to `true` (validated this in the Spark UI) and were hoping the other defaults like cleaner interval (1 day) and cleaner max age (7d) as mentioned at: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#spark-configuration-options would take care of cleaning up these logs.​ But that is not the case.

Any ideas?

[1]

```
-rwxrwx---   2 hadoop spark      543.1 M 2017-01-11 13:13 /var/log/spark/apps/application_1484079613665_0001
-rwxrwx---   2 hadoop spark        7.8 G 2017-01-17 10:51 /var/log/spark/apps/application_1484079613665_0002.inprogress
-rwxrwx---   2 hadoop spark        1.4 G 2017-01-18 08:11 /var/log/spark/apps/application_1484079613665_0003
-rwxrwx---   2 hadoop spark        2.9 G 2017-01-20 07:41 /var/log/spark/apps/application_1484079613665_0004
-rwxrwx---   2 hadoop spark      125.9 M 2017-01-20 09:57 /var/log/spark/apps/application_1484079613665_0005
-rwxrwx---   2 hadoop spark        4.4 G 2017-01-23 10:19 /var/log/spark/apps/application_1484079613665_0006
-rwxrwx---   2 hadoop spark        6.6 M 2017-01-23 10:31 /var/log/spark/apps/application_1484079613665_0007
-rwxrwx---   2 hadoop spark       26.4 M 2017-01-23 11:09 /var/log/spark/apps/application_1484079613665_0008
-rwxrwx---   2 hadoop spark       37.4 M 2017-01-23 11:53 /var/log/spark/apps/application_1484079613665_0009
-rwxrwx---   2 hadoop spark      111.9 M 2017-01-23 13:57 /var/log/spark/apps/application_1484079613665_0010
-rwxrwx---   2 hadoop spark        1.3 G 2017-01-24 10:26 /var/log/spark/apps/application_1484079613665_0011
-rwxrwx---   2 hadoop spark        7.0 M 2017-01-24 10:37 /var/log/spark/apps/application_1484079613665_0012
-rwxrwx---   2 hadoop spark       50.7 M 2017-01-24 11:40 /var/log/spark/apps/application_1484079613665_0013
-rwxrwx---   2 hadoop spark       96.2 M 2017-01-24 13:27 /var/log/spark/apps/application_1484079613665_0014
-rwxrwx---   2 hadoop spark      293.7 M 2017-01-24 17:58 /var/log/spark/apps/application_1484079613665_0015
-rwxrwx---   2 hadoop spark        7.6 G 2017-01-30 07:01 /var/log/spark/apps/application_1484079613665_0016
-rwxrwx---   2 hadoop spark        1.3 G 2017-01-31 02:59 /var/log/spark/apps/application_1484079613665_0017
-rwxrwx---   2 hadoop spark        2.1 G 2017-02-01 12:04 /var/log/spark/apps/application_1484079613665_0018
-rwxrwx---   2 hadoop spark        2.8 G 2017-02-03 08:32 /var/log/spark/apps/application_1484079613665_0019
-rwxrwx---   2 hadoop spark        5.4 G 2017-02-07 02:03 /var/log/spark/apps/application_1484079613665_0020
-rwxrwx---   2 hadoop spark        9.3 G 2017-02-13 03:58 /var/log/spark/apps/application_1484079613665_0021
-rwxrwx---   2 hadoop spark        2.0 G 2017-02-14 11:13 /var/log/spark/apps/application_1484079613665_0022
-rwxrwx---   2 hadoop spark        1.1 G 2017-02-15 03:49 /var/log/spark/apps/application_1484079613665_0023
-rwxrwx---   2 hadoop spark        8.8 G 2017-02-21 05:42 /var/log/spark/apps/application_1484079613665_0024
-rwxrwx---   2 hadoop spark      371.2 M 2017-02-21 11:54 /var/log/spark/apps/application_1484079613665_0025
-rwxrwx---   2 hadoop spark        1.4 G 2017-02-22 09:17 /var/log/spark/apps/application_1484079613665_0026
-rwxrwx---   2 hadoop spark        3.2 G 2017-02-24 12:36 /var/log/spark/apps/application_1484079613665_0027
-rwxrwx---   2 hadoop spark        9.5 M 2017-02-24 12:48 /var/log/spark/apps/application_1484079613665_0028
-rwxrwx---   2 hadoop spark       20.5 G 2017-03-10 04:00 /var/log/spark/apps/application_1484079613665_0029
-rwxrwx---   2 hadoop spark        7.3 G 2017-03-10 04:04 /var/log/spark/apps/application_1484079613665_0030.inprogress
```

Comment: What EMR AMI version are you using ? Are those container/executor logs ?  Are you using YARN mode ?

Comment: @swaranga-sarma Have you been able to fix this problem? We have been running into something similar where our 1 long running application never has its logs cleaned.

Comment: @Interfector I think ferris-tseng is correct. Going to try it out. Hitting similar issues

Comment: @GauravShah We've tried this solution, and it did not seem to do the trick. The reason for that is our application is long running. For cleanup to take place, the application needs to finish, it will not rotate logs for running applications. We had to completely disable Spark History Server.

Comment: @Interfector I guess we are going to hit the same issue. will look if I can find something else

Comment: @GauravShah Shah I can confirm that the solution posted by Ferris Tseng works. EMR support also recommends the same solution.

Comment: @SwarangaSarma but it would not work for long running applications right ? It cannot clear files that are currently being written. Got similar reply from AWS to disable the logs for long running app

Comment: @GauravShah No it does work. This is because these properties are used by the history server and not the actual Spark application. You don't need to restart the Spark application, you can just update the spark-defaults.conf and restart the history server. I have used it in our long running application and have had no problems for several months now. For the files that are currently being written, you do restart the application sometimes though right? What about new deployments etc?

Comment: @SwarangaSarma: I did not understand previous comment, are you saying for a running application the accepted answer below can reduce the log size, in my case I have a single file of 20GB , I have kept max age 1 hr and interval 1hr and still the event log file does not rotate - I have spark streaming application and I don't restart, just one application on EMR cluster

Comment: @supermonk - apologies. I misread your question. Your are correct that it will only cleanup the logs once the application restarts. Logs generated by the currently running app will not be cleaned up even though they might have expired your max age.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I was running into this issue on `emr-5.4.0`, and set `spark.history.fs.cleaner.interval` to `1h`, and was able to get the cleaner to run.

For reference, here is the end of my `spark-defaults.conf` file:

```
spark.history.fs.cleaner.enabled true
spark.history.fs.cleaner.maxAge  12h
spark.history.fs.cleaner.interval 1h
```

After you make the change, restart your spark history server.

**Another clarification**: Setting these values during application run, i.e `spark-submit` via `--conf` has no effect. Either set them at cluster creation time via the EMR configuration API or manually edit the spark-defaults.conf, set these values and restart the spark history server. Also note that the logs will be cleaned up the next time your Spark app restarts. For instance, if you have a long running Spark streaming job, it will not delete any logs for that application run and will keep accumulating logs. And when the next time the job restarts (may be because of a deployment) it will cleanup the older logs.

Comment: Confirmed that this works. There are two ways to do this really: 1. Add this during cluster creation. 2. Edit spark-defaults.conf and restart the history server.

Comment: will adding this clear the previous logs also that do not come under the max age bracket ?

Comment: @SwarangaSarma Do you mean that cleanup happens only when the application restarts? In that case, How do I deal with streaming jobs which need to run continuously?

Comment: @SaisumanthGopisetty in our case we do deployments fairly frequently (once a week) and that is enough for the cleanup.

Comment: Thanks @SwarangaSarma. Do you know how to deal with gigantic .inprogress logs in streaming applications?

Comment: Is there a way to manually run the cleaner process for the `/spark2-history` dir?

Comment: hello @SwarangaSarma , this works for me when i restrt the spark history server but it starts picking up old logs again. I am using nfs instead of hadoop.